# Ассоциативные массивы и как нарисовать круг и секторы?

Tags: css3, массивы, javascript, html

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты. Сегодня друг попросил помощи по Javascript. Мне необходимо сделать 2 задания.

**Задание 1**
Необходимо поменять в ассоциативном массиве местами ключи и значения.

Дело в том, что с ассоциативными массивами я имел оооочень поверхностный опыт общения на С++, в JS у меня появились некоторые вопросы. Во-первых, меня интересует каким образом его можно задать. Я сделал это через обычный цикл, но думаю, что это скорее всего неправильно:

```
      var arrayNums = {}; 
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) 
{   
key = i;    
znach = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-1 + 1)+ 1);     
arrayNums['' + key + ''] = znach;   
document.writeln(key);  
document.writeln(arrayNums[key] + '<br>'); 
}
```

В этом случае, как я понимаю, я просто создал обычный массив с обычной индексацией. В принципе это всё, что меня интересует по ассоциативным массивам.

**Задание 2** Необходимо создать круг, разделенный на 5 секторов. При наведении курсора сегмент уменьшается.

Изначально я хотел воспользоваться CSS 3.0 Опять же, сам опыта работы не имею, но заодно собирался и разобраться. Из всего, что я нашел в сети, ничего путнего не было. Это либо 4 сегмента (top, right, bottom, left), либо вообще что-то не то. Какие ещё альтернативные способы вы можете предложить? Есть варианты использования картинок, но по-моему, совсем неприемлимо и некруто. Буду очень благодарен за скорейший ответ, пока что попробую найти решение.

P.S. Решение должно быть только на чистом Javascript и HTML. Использовать jQuery не разрешается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
// если важна поддержка старых браузеров
// в общем случае, для получения ключей
// функция Object.keys предпочтительна
if(!Object.keys) {
 Object.keys = function(obj) {
  var keys = [];
  for(var i in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
   keys.push(i); 
  }
  return keys;
 }
}
```

---

```
function reverseObjectKeys(obj) {
 var res = {};
 var keys = Object.keys(obj);
 for(var i=0; i<keys.length; ++i) {
  var key = keys[i];
  res[obj[key]] = key;
 }
 return res;
}

var someHash = {key1:'value1',key2:'value2',keyN:'valueN'};
console.log(JSON.stringify(reverseObjectKeys(someHash), null, ' '));
/* console out
{
 "value1": "key1",
 "value2": "key2",
 "valueN": "keyN"
}
*/
```

2)

Как я понял у вас проблемы с тем, как нарисовать эти сегменты и, собственно, сам круг. Для этого используйте либо canvas, либо svg. Писать решение не буду т.к. это уже будет откровенная работа за автора.

PS: если это тестовое задание, то крайне рекомендую не обманывать потенциального работодателя и самого себя, если у вас вызвало сложности первое задание, то вам, определенно, нужно подтянуть матчасть.

Comment: нет-нет, ни о какой работе речь не идет. Я ещё студент. Первый курс. С таким уровнем знаний на работу соваться не позволит совесть)

Comment: @Vendetta8247, я только предположил, тогда удачи в обучении :)

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. Начал разбираться со вторым заданием и нашел достаточно точное решение с помощью SVG. До сегодня даже не знал о его существовании.

Comment: @Vendetta8247, нет проблем

Answer (score 0):

По первому пункту - вы создали не массив, а объект. Массив задается литералом `[]`, и в сущности не важно как его заполнять - в цикле или отдельными выражениями. Возможная проблема при замене мест ключей и значений - значения под разными ключами могут повторяться. Например каким должен быть ответ для такого массива: `['a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 'c': 'baz', 'd': 'foo']` ?
Но вот простейший код для смены ключей и значений:

```
var newarr = [];  
for (var key in oldarr) {  
  newarr[oldarr[key]] = key;  
}
```

Со вторым вопросом помочь не могу, увы.

Answer (score 0):

По заданию один
В JS нет ассоциативных массивов как таковых. За-то есть объекты. Что бы пройтись по ключам объекта, нужно использовать цикл for(in):

```
var Obj = new Object()             /*инициализируем объект */
Obj['key1'] = 'val1'
Obj['key2'] = 'val2'
Obj['key3'] = 'val3'               /*заполняем объект */
for(var key in Obj){
    var newKey = Obj[key]
    var newWalue = key
    delete Obj[key]               /*удаляем старое свойство объекта */
    Obj[newKey] = newValue
}
```